# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: x.y.z.BasicAuthHandler cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v7

Tags: wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 ESB Domain,Here i need to **Secure API by using BasicAuthHandler**.
I have done the process by referring this[1](https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/33136403/header/SecuringAPIs-BasicAuthUsingaBasicAuthhandler) and works fine.
But instead of passing admin as both username,password, need to pass wso2user as username and password.
What i did is simply copy that BasicAuthHandler code and edit username and password like my case(wso2user) under customized package name(x.y.z).

In API,calling that BasicAuthHandler by using handlers,

```
 <handlers>
    <handler class="x.y.z.BasicAuthHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

it throws exception like **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: x.y.z.BasicAuthHandler cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v7**

Can anyone please help me out to resolve this issue?
Thank You,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the synapse cannot find the x.y.z.BasicAuthHandler class. If you are changing the package name in the given sample project[[1](https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/33136403/header/SecuringAPIs-BasicAuthUsingaBasicAuthhandler)] make sure to update the source code of BasicAuthHandler class[[2](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk07/products/esb/4.8.1/modules/samples/integration-scenarios/starbucks_sample/BasicAuth-handler/src/main/java/org/wso2/rest/BasicAuthHandler.java)] with the new package name. Then build the project using maven and copy the generated jar file to repository/component/lib folder inside ESB.

Comment: Hi @Ranga,
 Thanks for your response.I have updated sourcecode of BasicAuthHandler class with my customized package name and Copied general jar[1] in following path repository/component/lib.
[1]https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk07/products/esb/4.8.1/modules/samples/integration-scenarios/starbucks_sample/bin/WSO2-REST-BasicAuth-Handler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
here i don't know how to take generated jar,that's why i am putting general jar by referreing [1]
Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi @Ranga,
Thank You so much, Because i have learn how to build the project using maven and then generating jar and finally works fine.